# [ jQuery/Datatable ]: datatables not responsive, disable an input search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I follow the example on the [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) in order to make a datatable with select input search.

Here's my **html** code example:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<table id="dataTables" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Référence</th>
          <th>Activité(s)</th>
          <th>Parc immobilier</th>
          <th>Nom du Bâtiment</th>
          <th>Ensemble</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Référence</th>
          <th>Activité(s)</th>
          <th>Parc immobilier</th>
          <th>Nom du Bâtiment</th>
          <th>Ensemble</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        {% for batiment in batiment %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ batiment.referencebatiment }}</td>
            <td>
              {% for batiment in batiment.typesactivite %}
                {{ batiment.type }}
                <br>
              {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>{{ batiment.ensembles.parcsimmobilier }}</td>
            <td>{{ batiment.nom }}</td>
            <td>{{ batiment.ensembles }}</td>
            <td><a href=""><button class="btn btn-edit btn-xs sharp">Modifier</button></a></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

So here's my **javascript** code for datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        //enlever la recherche sur une colone, ici la colone 2 et 4 => Office et Date. Attention 0 est une valeur, les colones commencent donc à partir de 0
        "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 5 ] }],
        //
        //langue française
        "language": {
            "sProcessing":     "Traitement en cours...",
            "sSearch":         "Rechercher&nbsp;:",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            "sInfo":           "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement en cours...",
            "sZeroRecords":    "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Aucune donn&eacute;e disponible dans le tableau",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":      "Premier",
                "sPrevious":   "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
                "sNext":       "Suivant",
                "sLast":       "Dernier"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
                "sSortDescending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre d&eacute;croissant"
            }
        },
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();
            api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                var column = api.column( i );
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    });
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Like you can see, I change the language in french, and disable search for colums 5, because I don't want allow user to make a search based on this colum. So the language changement and the disable search on the column 5 work really good.

Why my datatables don't display correctly. It's not collapsing well with bootstrap responsive design? How can I disable a search from a column (no input `text` or `select` in my `tfoot` under a column?

How can I do it?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: try to look at the doc [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.search%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Gab mentionned in his answer, you need to import the cdn of  jQuery dataTables like this:

First you need to disable or remove datatables CSS you have in your folders, if you don't it does not match or display correctly your `<table>`.

Then import CDN:
CSS: `//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.3/css/dataTables.responsive.css`
JS: `//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.3/js/dataTables.responsive.js`

Just in case, if you have any other data in your `<table>`, like an edit button, a link, you have to disable search on this column, if you don't your datatables will have some displaying problems.

Follow this ewample [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) in order to disable or don't display the search input in your `<tfoot>` you don't want.

Comment: Indeed, it matches well. In fact I have an edit button and some links which are no datas from my database (not dynamic datas so), I remove them and my datatables display correctly. I have to disable some inputs search in my `<tfoot>` table. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to import the cdn mentionned [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/)

CSS: `//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.3/css/dataTables.responsive.css`

JS: `//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.3/js/dataTables.responsive.js`